# SQL Server performance on concat method

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query to fetch some data from table and need to use concat method. I end up preparing two different queries and I'm not sure which one will have better performance when we have huge amounts of data.

Please help me understand which query will perform better, and why.

1. I need to concat twice, one for displaying and one for where condition:

```
select 
    id, concat(boolean_value, long_value, string_value, double_value) as Value  
from 
    table 
where 
    concat(boolean_value, long_value, string_value, double_value) = 'XX'
```

2. Write the above query as a subquery and add the where condition

```
Select * 
from 
    (select 
         id, concat(boolean_value, long_value, string_value, double_value) as Value          
     from 
         table) as output 
where 
    Value = 'XX'
```

Note: this is sample query and the actual query will have multiple joins and the need to concat from multiple columns of different tables

Comment: Check the execution plan. But I'd be very surprised if there are any differences in performance (most likely both end up with the same execution plan anyway)

Comment: I'd consider query 2. Easier to write correct, easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

SQL databases represent the result set being produced.  You seem to be asking if there is common expression elimination -- that is, will the `concat()` be performed exactly once.

You have a better chance of this with the subquery than with the version that repeat the expression.  But SQL Server could be smart enough to only evaluate it once.

If you want to guarantee single evaluation, then I think `cross apply` does that:

```
select t.id, v.value
from table t cross apply
     (values (concat( boolean_value, long_value, string_value, double_value))
     ) as Value
where v.value = 'XX';
```

I would, however, question why you are comparing the *result* of the `concat()` rather than the base columns.  Comparing the base columns would allow the optimizer to take advantage of indexes, partitions, and statistics.

Comment: Thanks Gordon: i shall try using cross apply also.. Its my requirement to get the details according to the concatenated value

Answer (score 2):

You may run `EXPLAIN` on both queries to see what exactly is on the mind of SQL Server.  I would expect that the first version would be preferable, because, unlike the second version, it does not force SQL Server to materialize an intermediate table.  Regarding whether or not SQL Server would have to actually evaluate `CONCAT` twice in the first version, it may not even matter if the cost of the subquery be very high.

Comment: Thanks Tim: i shall run Explain and check.